# Regex conditional

Tags: html, regex

How would I write a RegEx to:

Find a match where the first instance of a `>` character is before the first instance of a `<` character.

(I am looking for bad HTML where the closing `>` initially in a line has no opening `<`.)

Comment: This does assume that your HTML is formatted in a way that allows all HTML to be on one line. So if someone starts an HTML tag and closes it on the next line you'd get a false positive although the HTML would be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[^<>]*>
```

if you need the corresponding `<` as well,

```
^[^<>]*>[^<]*<
```

If there is a possibility of tags before the first `>`,

```
^[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]+>[^<>]*)*>
```

Note that it can give false positives, e.g.

```
<!-- > -->
```

is a valid HTML, but the RegEx will complain.

Comment: It seems as if this won't catch this a line with:  <tag1>  badtag2>

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty bad idea to try to parse html with regex, or even try to detect broken html with a regex.

What happens when there is a linebreak so that the > character is the first character on the line for example (valid html).

You might get some mileage from reading the answers to this question also: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
string =~ /^[^<]*>/
```

This should start at the beginning of the line, look for all characters that aren't an open '<' and then match if it finds a close '>' tag.

Comment: what happens if the > was a closing one from the line above?

Comment: I think that's a problem with the question. This will do what he asked it to do. To get the previous lines opens up the can-of-worms with using a regular expression to check a non-regular language.

Comment: In perl/ruby and other languages you can use the "m" modifier which will treat the entire string as one line regardless of line breaks. I re-read his question and he doesn't necessarily specify that it would be all on one line. `string =~ /^[^<]*>/m`